# My regular expression invalid .htm and html files

Tags: html, asp.net, regex, file-upload

I'm using this regular expression validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rExpNuevoFlash" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileNuevoFlash" ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Ss][Ww][Ff])|.*\.([Hh][Tt][Mm])|.*\.([Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll])|.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Ee][gG])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])$)"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender6" runat="server" TargetControlID="rFvalNuevoFlash"></ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

When tried to upload an .htm or .html file, for some weird reason my validator responded false, and error message was shown with Validator Callout Extender, what am I doing bad. thank you.

Comment: The regex looks okay to me, although you should probably put `.html` before `.htm` since your regex is lazy and will always try to ignore the L in `.html` if it finds `.htm` first.

Comment: oh my good, you right, thank you so much!.

Comment: how can i close this question or something like that ¿?.

Comment: I just added an answer.  You can mark it as the correct answer now.  Glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `.html` before `.htm`, it should work.  Your regex is lazy, so it is ignoring `.html` because it is finding `.htm` first.

Comment: thank you again, its a little embarrasing for me this noob question lol thank you.